# Generating a msix package for a .NET MAUI Blazor application and signing it separately

Tags: blazor, maui, code-signing, msix, appxmanifest

**Problem**

I'm no longer able to generate a signed msix package from Visual Studio, since the signing process now requires a a piece of hardware, and I don't have that hardware. I need to generate the msix package and send it to someone else to that they can sign it.

**Possible solutions that I can think of**

1. I could use a self signed certificate, generate the msix package and then send it to the signer. However, I don't want the self signed certificate to be part of the final msix package, so it sounds like a bad idea.
2. I came across a text (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/unsigned-package) that supposedly explains how to generate an unsigned msix package. However, it looks like it is only meant to explain how to *install* the package.
3. Maybe I could somehow zip my project files and send it to the signer, but I don't think they could create an msix file from them. They have specifically requested an msix file, so they probably have a code signing software where they have to click on a specific msix file to sign it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answere.

I went to the project file for my .NET MAUI Blazor project and set this row:

```
<AppxPackageSigningEnabled>False</AppxPackageSigningEnabled>
```

After this I could use dotnet publish to publish an unsigned version.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the document about [Publish a .NET MAUI app for Windows with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/windows/deployment/publish-visual-studio-folder?view=net-maui-8.0).

In the step three Select Signing Method dialog, You can see that you can choose the option one to skip the package signing. Then you can create a MSIX package without the signing.

Last, you can send the MSIX package to the signer then then can [use the SignTool to sign the MSIX package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/msix/package/sign-app-package-using-signtool).

Comment: Thank you for your answere. Unfortunately, that guide always crashes for me so I use the dotnet publish command instead. I can't find a parameter to modify dotnet publish to that it doesn't sign.